# Angular $filter not updating variable on array returned by $resource

Tags: filter, angularjs, xmlhttprequest, angular-resource

Say I've got an Angular `$resource` that returns an array of `entries` that all have a `name` attribute. I would like to use `$filter` **in Javascript** (**not** using Angular's `{{ blah | filter:filter }}` syntax within the templates) to extract a subset of those entries  based on the attribute.

The code would look something like:

```
app.controller('AppController', function ($scope, Project, $filter) {
    $scope.entries = Project.query();
    $scope.entry = $filter('filter')($scope.entries, {name: 'Bar'});
    ...
}
```

However, as illustrated in this [jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/mMRfV/5/), the snippet won't work as intended. `entry` will contain an empty array regardless of what `entries` gets populated with asynchronously, when the XHR completes. Setting up a `$scope.$watch` also doesn't work.

I want to update `entry` according to the filter when `entries` is populated with data. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I was pretty much done with my question when I experimented a bit more and found that I could do this by supplying a `success` callback to the `query()` call:

```
app.controller('AppController', function ($scope, Project, $filter) {
    $scope.entries = Project.query({}, function() {
        $scope.entry = $filter('filter')($scope.entries, {name: 'Bar'});
    });
    ...
}
```

See the [updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mMRfV/6/).