# AngularJS Filter REST JSON in Controller

Tags: json, angularjs, rest

I need to output a count of items from JSON by category (using `.length` I believe), and would like to manage this in a controller so I can place it to scope anywhere I want. How can I filter REST JSON in a controller?

My sample JSON is as follows:

```
[
    {
        "id": "66D5069C-DC67-46FC-8A51-1F15A94216D4",
        "articletitle": "artilce1",
        "articlecategoryid": 1,
        "articlesummary": "article 1 summary. "
    },
    {
        "id": "66D5069C-DC67-46FC-8A51-1F15A94216D5",
        "articletitle": "artilce2",
        "articlecategoryid": 2,
        "articlesummary": "article 2 summary. "
    }, 
    {
        "id": "66D5069C-DC67-46FC-8A51-1F15A94216D6",
        "articletitle": "artilce3",
        "articlecategoryid": 3,
        "articlesummary": "article 3 summary. "
    },   
    {
        "id": "66D5069C-DC67-46FC-8A51-1F15A94216D7",
        "articletitle": "artilce4",
        "articlecategoryid": 1,
        "articlesummary": "article 3 summary. "
    }, 
]
```

My Resource is as follows:

```
// Articles by ID
pfcServices.factory('pfcArticles', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('https://myrestcall.net/tables/articles', {},
    {
        'update': { method:'PATCH'}
    });
}]);
```

My Controller is as follows:

```
// Count number of total articles
pfcControllers.controller('pfcArticleCountCtrl', ['$scope', 'pfcArticles', function ($scope, pfcArticles) {
    $scope.articlecount = pfcArticles.query();
```

I believe I would need to add something to the controller (ex. `$scope.cat1 = filter(my logic to get my category here)`, but am a little lost on how to query this so I have a count of items per category.

Comment: Thank you for the edits. I will try to follow that in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build a filter like this.

```js
angular.module('FilterModule', [])
  .filter( 'cat1', function() {
    return function(yourJSON) {
      var count = 0;
      yourJSON.forEach(function(item) {
        switch(item.articlecategoryid) {
          case 1:
            count++;
            break;
          default:
            console.log('item is not of category 1');      
        }  
      });
      return count;
    };
  });
```

Inject the $filter service and fetch the `cat1` filter. Now you can use it as `$scope.cat1 = $filter('cat1')(yourJSON);`

Comment: How would I use this for each category. Would I have it switch case for 2, etc. Would this exist with my controller that retrieves my REST call?

Comment: I suggest to create a single filter that returns count object containing counts of each category, which checks for all cases. I created a separate module for the filter. Include this module as a dependency for your app module and inject `$filter` into your controller. Use this filter as `$scope.cat1= $filter('cat1')(yourJSON)` (correction of earlier answer). For all categories count object `$scope.categoryCountsObj = $filter('categoriesCount')(yourJSON);`

Comment: Would something like this work as well? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15273385/angular-filter-not-updating-variable-on-array-returned-by-resource

Comment: Yes. It will work. Nice approach utilizing the inbuilt text search feature. `$scope.cat1Count = $filter('filter')(yourJSON, {"articlecategoryid": 1});` Don't forget to inject `$filter` into your controller.

Comment: Thank you. I will test and let you know how it turns out.